# Filtering collection by model custom method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I'm using Laravel for a project and i want to filter a collection based on custom method written in the model:

Controller:

```
$models= Produs::with('categorie')
        ->with('poza')
        ->with('element_extra.extras')
        ->get()
        ->where('id_stare', 1)
        ->where('categorie.id_restaurant', $idRestaurant)
        ->groupBy('categorie.denumire');

        
        $produse = $models->filter(function ($produs, $key) {
            return $produs->isAvailable();
        })->values();
```

Model:

```
class Produs extends Model
{

    protected $table = "elemente";
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    public function isAvailable(){

        if(...something....){

            return false;

        }else{

            return true;

        }

    }
```

This is what i get:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::isAvailable does not exist.
```

Comment: `groupBy` returns collection inside the collection, what's why you can't filter it. Please, add the full description of the task to allow find better solution

Comment: I have some products grouped by categories but this products have a schedule_id .In isAvaible function i want to get the schedule that is correspondent to the product and calculate if now() is in the schedule.If is not the isAvaible return false else return true.

Comment: The `get()` should go at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add keyword `scope` to your method

```
public function scopeIsAvailable($query) {
    return $query->where('active', true);
}
```

and after that call it like this

```
$models= Produs::isAvailable()...
```

Comment: the condition in my if is not a query is something more complex.

Answer (score 0):

:: double colon usage is for static functions.

try to use

```
public static function isAvailable(){}
```

Comment: If i use static, i can't use $this.